# Symfony2 and security roles configuration

Tags: security, symfony, acl, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to configure Symfony ACL:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_A }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_A:           ROLE_USER
    ROLE_B:           ROLE_A
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_B
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

So: `A` extends from `USER`, `B` from `A` etc.

The problem is that when I login as `ADMIN` or `SUPER_ADMIN` I'm getting `403` Not Authorized. It only works when I'm authorized as `A`. Why? What I'm doing wrong with role extending?

Comment: Can you post your whole security config

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6XWiNfff). Thanks!

Comment: I have a very similar config to yours, I also use FOSUserBundle (I don´t use JMSSecurity extra, but I don´t think this matters) and I tried your role hierarchy and for me it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the role hierarchy should be defined top-down. So in the above example you should have:

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_B
        ROLE_B:           ROLE_A
        ROLE_A:           ROLE_USER
```

Comment: Hi Krzysztof,Thank you for your reply. Accordig to book I was sure that "minor" roles should go first: (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles). I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to be

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_B, ROLE_A, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_B, ROLE_A, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_B:           [ROLE_A, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_A:           ROLE_USER
```

Comment: see [security config reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)